# What retains disconnected custom objects in Storyboard scene?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have custom class:

```
class TempObject: NSObject {
    static var count = 0;

    override init() {
        super.init()
        println("init: \(++TempObject.count)")
    }
    deinit {
        println("deinit \(TempObject.count--)")
    }
}
```

Then I've added this object to my Storyboard scene in accordance with ["Adding a Custom Object - Interface Builder Object and Media Help"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH9-SW1).

Just added, *no* `IBOutlet` connection to the View Controller.

When I run the app, `deinit` is *not* called.

```
 init: 1
```

That means something - not mine - retains this object. What is that? This behavior is guaranteed? Any official document about it?

Comment: Is the View Controller that holds the custom object deinitialized when you're expecting the custom object to be deinitialized?

I strongly assume that the lifetime of the object is tied to the lifetime of the View Controller.

Comment: @Ben-G Yes it's deinitialized when the view controller is deinitialized. And I also think your assumption is collect. But I want to know it's guaranteed, or widely known at least.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It seems undocumented, but it makes sense that top level objects, e.g. the main UIView and custom objects are retained by the ViewController they are associated with.